# Magento 2.2.2 Custom theme Xml update external script with query string & or &amp;

Tags: magento2, layout-update, custom-theme

Adding external link in custom theme in any xml e.g: contact_index_index.xml doe not parse properly if it has & or &

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&amp;callback=initMap" src_type="url" />
```

Notice the `&amp;`  gives:

```
{"0":"Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 6371: parser error : EntityRef: expecting ';' in \/var\/www\/vhosts\/magento2 \/htdocs\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/View\/Model\/Layout\/Merge.php
```

Does anyone experiencing this too and how to fix it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way that I found it works is by using head.aditional:

e.g

```
        <referenceBlock name="head.additional">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Text" name="my_script">
                <action method="setText">
                    <argument translate="true" name="text" xsi:type="string">
                        <![CDATA[<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&amp;callback=initMap" src_type="url" />]]>
                    </argument>
                </action>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<head>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&amp;callback=initMap" src_type="url"/>
</head>
</page>
```

Comment: no difference to mine buddy DOES not work. Compare my link :<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&amp;callback=initMap" src_type="url" />

Comment: than, could you please more explain to me